# Opportunity Amount Split over Quarters for Forecasting

Tags: opportunity, loop

I need to take the Opportunity Amount field in a trigger and split the amount into fields by Quarter.

So if the Amount of the Opportunity is 24,000,000 over 24 months the amount would be 3,000,000 per quarter. The result would be something like:

Opportunity.Q1_2017_Revenue__c = 3,000,000
etc....

What I can not figure out is how to get the information from a trigger and then how to loop through only the Quarter fields to apply the right amount based on the length of the contract.

Can you suggest how I should approach, provide or refer to example, provide a better path.

Comment: I apologize for the previous comment; I meant to link this feature: [Establish Schedules for Products on Opportunities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=products_establish.htm). You can use the built-in feature to schedule revenue.

Comment: sfdcfox, Thank you but I am lost as I do not understand. Can you be more explicit?